# Why this Regex selects parenthesis and after though I use look ahead

Tags: javascript, regex

I use this regex

```
/\.(.+)?(?=(\(?)|\r\n)/gi
```

with

```
part1.part2
part1.part2(part3) part4
```

I want only match .part2 in both cases

but in second case I get .part2(part3) part4

[image]

Comment: https://regexper.com/#%2F%5C.%28.%2B%29%3F%28%3F%3D%28%5C%28%3F%29%7C%5Cr%5Cn%29%2Fgi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make the `.+` part non-greedy, by using `.+?`, as otherwise it will also capture the opening parenthesis you want to see in the look-ahead part.

Also, in the second part, don't make the `\(` optional, otherwise you will be OK in having nothing in your look-ahead to match.

Finally, don't match `\r\n`, but the end-of-line anchor `$` in combination with the `m` flag (so that it matches the end of each line instead of the whole input).

So:

`\.(.+?)(?=\(|$)`

[regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/mItjrj/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You see the parenthesis in the match as the `.` can also match `(`.

The pattern will match the rest of the line after the first dot without backtracking to a `(` as the parenthesis in the lookahead is optional `\(?` and the assertion will be true.

You could make use of a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) not crossing parenthesis or a newline when matching.

```
\.([^()\r\n]+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/K9i9hc/1)